# Mesh issues after using boolean modifier

Tags: modeling

I've been following Blender Guru's anvil tutorial, and although I have a (seemingly) ok mesh, the subdivision modifier isn't  working correctly, as I get a hard seam where the area carved out by the boolean modifier is. I've attached the [Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BFYwDsdh8kD5xyfE8v1oXKLGO0y2uV9R/view?usp=sharing) below if anyone would like to take a look at it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the .blend file, and it seems you just need to recalculate the normals on the areas carved out by the boolean modifier. There's also a stray edge near the base of the anvil that's creating some ugly topology. Remove that stray edge and recalculate the normals and everything should be good to go!